# How to get an URL of an image which has been stored on server

Tags: php, html, url, image-uploading

It must be very easy but I have no clue how to get the URL of an image from server.

Lets say I have domain named www.example.com and the image has been stored in my

```
htdocs>www>resources>userid>images>image.jpg
```

So, I want upload an image and save it through php script into my images folder and return the URL of that image back to browser like,

```
www.example.com/.../.../images/image.jpg
```

Is there any php function to get URL of a file?

### EDIT:

After looking at answer I thought I should more clarify my self. I am really sorry for misunderstanding,

**The help I wanted is to :** what if the domain name isn't static I mean you can download and attach my image uploader plugin to your website but now it should dynamically get domain name and http path to your image.

Comment: I don't get it. Your script knows the path where it saves the file, so  it should know the URL too.

Comment: @bažmegakapa, Sorry for misunderstanding I have updated my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since i don't have your plugin, i don't know the flow of your code. My guess below, hopefully, you can modify it according to your code.

Suppose i download your plugin to my website and upload an image using it. You can get the image path like this:

```
<?php
$upload_path = 'PATH_WHERE_IMAGE_IS_UPLOADED';
$image_name = 'NAME_OF_THE_UPLOADED_IMAGE';

$relative_path = $upload_path . DS . $image_name;

$path = str_replace( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
                                                            , $relative_path );

$path = 'http://' . $path; // this is where image is uploaded
?>
```

**Note:** This assumes that the upload directory is within the webroot.

Hopefully, this will work.

Comment: @Craftero - I modified my response. Please have a look.

Comment: Ohhh so we can use $_SERVER[] seems like it helps to get global variables. Thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$image='name of your image uploaded';
$imageurl='http://www.example.com/images'.$image;
echo '<input type=text name="image" value="'.$imageurl.'" disabled />;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Editted**

If you have for example:

```
$domain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$uploadPath = "/htdocs/www/resources/userid/images/image.jpg"

// replace "/htdocs/www", with an empty string
$subdir = str_replace("/htdocs/www", "", $uploadPath);

$url = $domain.$subdir;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at manual page of PHP function [move_uploaded_file()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php). If I understand your problem, solution is there.